# How can I find out who is responsible for Django's CSRF middleware?

Tags: django, django-csrf

How can I find out who is responsible for Django's CSRF middleware so I could ask them questions?

I'm having so many CSRF failures for months on my Django site and it is costing me hours and hours of problems every few weeks.  I want to contact the developers who worked on it to ask them one or two root questions about the problems I'm having.

I put up several other posts about the problems that never get satisfactory answers, but that do result in a few work arounds:
[Django CSRF framework cannot be disabled and is breaking my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650941/django-csrf-framework-cannot-be-disabled-and-is-breaking-my-site)
[Django CSRF Framework having many failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765723/django-csrf-framework-having-many-failures)
[Tons of false positives from Django's CSRF middleware?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467425/tons-of-false-positives-from-djangos-csrf-middleware)
[For Django's CSRF failure middleware, how can you get the CSRF errors to report what URL is failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010432/for-djangos-csrf-failure-middleware-how-can-you-get-the-csrf-errors-to-report-w)

Some other people are having the same types of frustrations:
[Completely disable Django's CSRF protection in SVN Trunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785772/completely-disable-djangos-csrf-protection-in-svn-trunk)

Comment: Finding contact information for a person is not really a programming question...

Comment: Well they are contributors to an open source project.  They must be listed somewhere in the code or the django community.

Comment: Why don't you post your problem here? Lots of people are using CSRF middleware without any problems. Which version of django are you using?

Comment: How many thousands of dollars are they saving you by providing you with a free framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSRF protection is being re-worked for Django 1.2.  See the community wiki page [CsrfProtection](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CsrfProtection) that discusses the current limitations and proposals for re-working.  Personally I'm thinking about moving ahead and using Simon Willison's [django-safeform](http://github.com/simonw/django-safeform) project as a temporary solution until 1.2 is released.

Answer (score 3):

I've said this before, but *you should not be using trunk* for production projects. Use the stable release, and you won't have any problems.